# How can I change Kestrel (AspNetCore) listening port by environment variables in netcore3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel

I have aspnetcore3.1 project, and I want to set custom port for Kestrel (other than default 5000). I can possibly do it in `Program.cs` by adding

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
{
    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ListenLocalhost(80);
    });
    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
})
```

But this cannot be applied to my case, so wondered, how can this be done by environment variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration).

> 1. ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable.
> 2. --urls command-line argument.
> 3. urls host configuration key.
> 4. UseUrls extension method.

To achieve this using an environment variable, simply create an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_URLS` and set the value to the URL you'd like to use

Typically this would be `http://+:<port>` or `https://+:<port>`

Another method which, at the time of writing this answer, isn't described above is via the hostsettings.json file.

You can configure the URL & Port by creating a hostsettings.json configuration file and adding the `urls` key, then add hostsettings.json to your `IConfigurationBuilder` when building your `WebHostBuilder`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#override-configuration

Here is the code snippet from the link, in case this link ever goes dead.

Create your hostsettings.json file containing the `urls` key with your value(s)

```json
{
    urls: "http://*:5005"
}
```

Register hostsettings.json in your `IConfigurationBuilder`

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
            .AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: --URLs argument works for me on .NET 3.1 on Ubuntu, tnx.

Comment: @Soren worth bearing in mind that this only works when `args` is passed to `CreateDefaultBuilder`, should you ever find yourself in a scenario where this stops working post-refactoring/cleanup.

Comment: @ColinM I'm pretty sure this little comment has saved me hours of head scratching. Thanks!