# Can Kestrel be used on Windows Server 2016 to host gRPC Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, grpc, iis-10, kestrel

I realize now that IIS cannot be used on Windows Server 2016 to host a gRPC Service (I'd need Windows Server 2022).

However .. the somewhat ambiguous MS docs seem to indicate that Kestrel could be used .. so I'm wondering how to properly set that up (in configs or c# code) on Windows 2016 Server?

I just read that Kestrel listens to All ports on an ip so that would be a problem as I have several IIS web sites running.

I just encountered an older link from a few years ago that described having IIS work as a reverse proxy and forward the request to a specific port that Kestrel is listening on?

That sounds rather advantageous as I could use the IIS SSL certificates that are already setup (and auto renewed) for the web site domain I intend to use.

So my question is .. how do I make this work?   Has anyone used Kestrel on a production server or possibly used IIS to reverse proxy to to Kestrel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change Kestrel (AspNetCore) listening port by environment variables in netcore3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152009/how-can-i-change-kestrel-aspnetcore-listening-port-by-environment-variables-in)

Comment: "Kestrel listens to All ports" no it doesn't, it just picks a random one between 5000 and 5300, see the docshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/self-hosted#https-certificates-for-self-hosted-applications Docs like this cover all you needed. Besides, "because some of the HTTP/2 functionality isn't supported" indicates the limitation is IIS only, so self-hosting should be fine.

Comment: As Kestrel comes with ASP.NET CORE, it should work!!

I'll use Postman from Inside the server as a client for gRPC using http.  Then see if I can reverse proxy from IIS to the internal Kestrel server with just http from the Outside and then check https which I think will just forward to http on the internal Kestrel?  

Using IIS with Kestrel will solve my SSL issue as I've already got IIS certificates the the domain auto-updated from Let's Encrypt.

So .. it's just a matter of setting up Kestrel configs in code or json and getting a simple test case working!!  Famous last words lol.

Comment: I've tried forwarding to Kestrel using URL Rewrite along with ARR.  I've tried running in Kestrel and listening on a port visible from the outside (and of course giving tcp permissions to the port thru the firewall.

Nothing seems to work on Windows Server 2016 - although I Can connect to gRPC Server using Kestrel inside the server with Postman.

So I'm attempting to use JSON Transcoding to bypass the HTTP/2 issue and use HTTP/1.

It Should work but I'm guessing MS is crippling it in some fashion as they want to sell Windows 2022 where I understand it Will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Not successful with get Kestrel to host a gRPC HTTP/2 service on Windows Server 2016.

It may be possible using some routine technique but I realized with I tested the localhost Kestrel version that it was taking 10x a long to return a query to Postman located on the server as it took to get the Same request using gRPC Json Transcoding (using Postman as a client) from several hundred miles away on my development box.

So what I learned is that Json Transcoding provides a quite decent response time and I'll just upgrade to HTTP/2 gRPC when I move the server to Windows 2022 or above.